# Limit Keycloak worker threads

Tags: docker, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am currently trying to host a small spring boot backend with an oauth server via docker.

The vServer I choose has unfortunately a limit of 400 Process/Kernel-Threads set in the /proc/user_beancounters.

When starting the jwilder/nginx-proxy, the spring boot app with db (set to only 1 tomcat thread) and the Keycloak server with db this limit is exceeded and everything stalls.

My approach is to limit the workers in Keycloak since I don't need this many.

```
14:35:23,948 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 IO threads with 64 max task threads based on your 4 available processors
```

But I really can't find any explanation on how to configure this parameter in Keycloak.

So the question: How can I configure the limit? Or maybe there is a better approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this in `standalone.xml` of the WildFly/Keycloak instance. Parameters are under `io` subsystem:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:3.0">
    <worker name="default" io-threads="8" task-max-threads="64"/>
    <buffer-pool name="default"/>
</subsystem>
```